# Wrong matplotlib animation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following code that should draw a cycloid with animation and save it to a gif
but after running the program, a white square appears that covers everything, I can't find the reason [cycloid_animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqqU4.gif)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, PillowWriter 
plt.rcParams['animation.html'] = 'html5'
R = 1
def circle(a, b, r):
    # (a,b): the center of the circle
    # r: the radius of the circle
    # T: The number of the segments
    T = 100
    x, y = [0]*T, [0]*T
    for i,theta in enumerate(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,T)):
        x[i] = a + r*np.cos(theta)
        y[i] = b + r*np.sin(theta)
    return x, y

# Calculate the cycloid line
thetas = np.linspace(0,4*np.pi,100)
cycloid_x = R*(thetas-np.sin(thetas))
cycloid_y = R*(1-np.cos(thetas))
cycloid_c = R*thetas
fig = plt.figure()

lns = []
trans = plt.axes().transAxes
for i in range(len(thetas)):
    x,y = circle(cycloid_c[i], R, R)
    ln1, = plt.plot(x, y, 'g-', lw=2)
    ln2, = plt.plot(cycloid_x[:i+1] ,cycloid_y[:i+1], 'r-', lw=2)
    ln3, = plt.plot(cycloid_x[i], cycloid_y[i], 'bo', markersize=4)
    ln4, = plt.plot([cycloid_c[i], cycloid_x[i]], [R,cycloid_y[i]], 'y-', lw=2)
    tx1  = plt.text(0.05, 0.8, r'$\theta$ = %.2f $\pi$' % (thetas[i]/np.pi), transform=trans)
    lns.append([ln1,ln2,ln3,ln4,tx1])
plt.xlim(0,15)
plt.ylim(0,3)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid()
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, lns, interval=50)
#ani.save('cycloid_ArtistAnimation.mp4',writer='ffmpeg')
ani.save('cycloid_ArtistAnimation.gif',writer='pillow')
ani
```

Answer (score 4):

Each time you call **plt.axis()** you are creating a new axis on top of the figure. Since what you want is to get the current axis and then apply the transformations, after creating the figure you should call **plt.gca()** to get the current axis and use that instead.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, PillowWriter 
plt.rcParams['animation.html'] = 'html5'
R = 1
def circle(a, b, r):
    # (a,b): the center of the circle
    # r: the radius of the circle
    # T: The number of the segments
    T = 100
    x, y = [0]*T, [0]*T
    for i,theta in enumerate(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,T)):
        x[i] = a + r*np.cos(theta)
        y[i] = b + r*np.sin(theta)
    return x, y

# Calculate the cycloid line
thetas = np.linspace(0,4*np.pi,100)
cycloid_x = R*(thetas-np.sin(thetas))
cycloid_y = R*(1-np.cos(thetas))
cycloid_c = R*thetas
fig = plt.figure()

lns = []
trans = plt.gca().transAxes #<=== HERE
for i in range(len(thetas)):
    x,y = circle(cycloid_c[i], R, R)
    ln1, = plt.plot(x, y, 'g-', lw=2)
    ln2, = plt.plot(cycloid_x[:i+1] ,cycloid_y[:i+1], 'r-', lw=2)
    ln3, = plt.plot(cycloid_x[i], cycloid_y[i], 'bo', markersize=4)
    ln4, = plt.plot([cycloid_c[i], cycloid_x[i]], [R,cycloid_y[i]], 'y-', lw=2)
    tx1  = plt.text(0.05, 0.8, r'$\theta$ = %.2f $\pi$' % (thetas[i]/np.pi), transform=trans)
    lns.append([ln1,ln2,ln3,ln4,tx1])
plt.xlim(0,15)
plt.ylim(0,3)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal') #<=== And HERE
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, lns, interval=50)
#ani.save('cycloid_ArtistAnimation.mp4',writer='ffmpeg')
ani.save('cycloid_ArtistAnimation.gif',writer='pillow')
```